# How to retrieve ports in use in the system?

Tags: linux, network-programming

In a Linux specific way, how can I get the list of all open UDP ports and all TCP ports currently accepting connections in some interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common way is to use netstat console utility with the following flags:

```
netstat -plan
```

where:

```
-p : Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs;
-l : Show only listening sockets;
-a : Show both listening and non-listening sockets;
-n : Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.
```

For additional output options and flags please check man pages `man netstat`. Based on your particular needs, only TCP or UDP (for example) protocol connections can be examined:

```
netstat -4 --tcp --udp --all
```

Alternatively, `lsof -i` might be helpful.

Most likely you are interested in the following information (special /proc filesystem):

/proc - Mount point for the proc filesystem, which gives access to kernel status information via the following files:

- /proc/net/dev - device information
- /proc/net/raw - raw socket information
- /proc/net/tcp - TCP socket information
- /proc/net/udp - UDP socket information
- /proc/net/igmp - IGMP multicast information
- /proc/net/unix - Unix domain socket information
- /proc/net/ipx - IPX socket information
- /proc/net/ax25 - AX25 socket information
- /proc/net/appletalk - DDP (appletalk) socket information
- /proc/net/nr - NET/ROM socket information
- /proc/net/route - IP routing information
- /proc/net/ax25_route - AX25 routing information
- /proc/net/ipx_route - IPX routing information
- /proc/net/nr_nodes - NET/ROM nodelist
- /proc/net/nr_neigh - NET/ROM neighbours
- /proc/net/ip_masquerade - masqueraded connections
- /proc/net/snmp - statistics

Comment: To span another process to do this work is not a viable solution for me. Do you know where these utilities takes their information from?

Answer (score 0):

List all listening processes and what port they are listening too. Running without sudo will list only user processes.

```
sudo ss -tlpn
```

explanation:

- `-t` tcp
- `-l` listening
- `-p` show process
- `-n` numeric, don't replace port numbers with their "popular" name.